# Fermat's Last Theorem algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm taking [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) definition of Fermat's Last Theorem.

I tried to code an algorithm to validate it for small values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    //a^n + b^n = c^n

    int a, b, c, n, count = 0;

    for (n = 3; n < 1000; n++)
        for (a = 1; a < 1000; a++)
            for (b = 1; b < 100; b++)
                for (c = 1; c < 1000; c++)
                {
                    if (a != b && b != c && a != c)
                    {
                        if (pow(a,n) + pow(b,n) == pow(c,n))
                        {
                            cout << "\na: " << a << " b: " << b << " c: " << c << " n: " << n;
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }

    cout << count << " combinazioni";

}
```

And this is a screen of a piece of output:
[image]

How is it be possible? Am I missing something about "great integers" in C++ programming that can get a wrong result?

Comment: Are you aware of the Mathematics forum at http://math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I think you want to collect empirical evidence upto some n in ℤ, rather than prove. @MarcAudet I think this is still an overflow question if we dump the whole proof business.

Comment: @MarcAudet Any question containing code is generally off topic for [math.se].

Comment: A brute force proof will take infinitely long to complete.

Comment: Hint: `cout << pow(c, n) <<endl;`

Comment: OMG You've found a counterexample to Fermat's Last Theorem !!!

Comment: Very entertaining question. Reads like a good attempt of a proof against last Fermat's theorem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your pow() functions are overflowing; remember an `int` has a limited size.

For example, pow(256, 4) will overflow on 32 bit, pow(256, 8) on 64 bit, even if you use unsigned data types.

Technically `int` overflow is *undefined behaviour* so, **anything** could happen, including wrap around (i.e. back to 0), or *nasal demons*.

`unsigned int` computations are modulo 2 raised to the power of WIDTH as per the standard; i.e. will always wrap around.

Comment: He is probably calling [std::pow](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) here which uses floats. Which still makes it an overflow, but the nature of the overflow is even more complex.

Comment: Good point. Although I have a pow() overload for two integers.

Comment: Isn't it only UB for *signed* integers?

Comment: There is no overflow for unsigned integers, computations on those are modulo `2^WIDTH` per the standard. **However**, here we have a `double` result from `pow()`, and converting an out-of-range value from a floating point type to an unsigned integer type invokes undefined behaviour, in contrast to converting from an integer type. (cc @harold) (And here we have signed integers anyway.)

Comment: @harold - you are correct; I've amended my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer; I've amended my answer to include modulo 2^WIDTH

Answer (score 7):

> Am I missing something

You are. Quite a lot actually. Let me enumerate.

1. **Types**. Not all numbers in C++ are integers. In particular, the result of `pow` is not an integer.
2. **Precision**. Those types which are not integers have limited precision in C++. In mathematics, 1 and 1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000982 are different numbers. In your C++ program, good luck with that.
3. **Limits**. Both integer and non-integer numbers in C++ are limited in the range of values they can assume. A variable of type `int` is guaranteed to be able to hold numbers between -32767 to 32767 inclusively. Many implementations in fact support quite a bit more than that, say -2147483648 to 2147483647. Many implementations have other types that can hold larger ranges of numbers, e.g. 0 to 18446744073709551616 or sometimes to 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 or even to 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936. (If you can take logarithms of 100-digit numbers in your head, you will notice that all of these limits are powers of 2 or something close to that). For comparison, 927 to the power of 104 is 376957467458457979751155893254582133603833255821602148851832991547421266649046326838345134050350882042675908426098865621401193999321757163912667101283653576225503152314408933435079267041822928198211089834145222519701307017745008621307049171220994632585789166175212394809510781938945415209193278956111609706241.

Answer (score 2):

`int` values are limited to 32 bit (including the sign bit), so that high values "wrap" beyond 2147483647. C/C++ have no built-in data type for arbitrarily large values.

To reduce the problem somewhat, you can use the type `long` or `unsigned long` (64 bit on 64-bit platforms). Some compilers support 64 bit on 32-bit platforms, too, if you use `long long`.

Edit: as pointed out in a comment below, the limits don't apply equally to all implementations of C/C++, but for most non-embedded systems you'll see today, those are the limits you're going to see.

Comment: -1 Actual sizes of integer types are implementation defined in C++. In particular, `int` is not always 32 bits in size and `long` is not always larger than `int` (although both is true for the IDE showing in the Op's screenshot).

Comment: Correct. I could've explained it more generally, but it makes no difference in the context of this particular question. There is no implementation that I know of that could fit `pow(927, 104)` into an `int`. Thanks for clarifying, though.